# Visitor on a business object in the domain in hexagonal/onion architecture?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, visitor-pattern, onion-architecture, hexagonal-architecture

I'm using hexagonal architecture and I wonder how a visitor pattern would respect it ?

The visited object is a domain object, but the visitor aims to dynamically dispatch said domain object implementations to appropriate mappers between domain object and data transfert object.

My first thought would be to expose the abstraction of the visitor into domain and leave its actual implementations into infra, similar to a repository.

Isn't it revealing infra into domain ? Visitor pattern is implementation details, right ? It doesn't bring any business value, so it doesn't belong to domain, isn't it ? However I need the accept method into my business object to achieve this pattern.

What are you thoughts about it ?

EDIT Code example (C# syntax but nothing fancy):

```
namespace Domain
{
    public interface IFlow
    {
        void Accept(IFlowVisitor visitor);
    }

    public class Cashflow : IFlow
    {
        void Accept(IFlowVisitor visitor)
        {
            visitor.Visit(this);
        }

        // some properties
    }

    public class Assetflow : IFlow
    {
        void Accept(IFlowVisitor visitor)
        {
            visitor.Visit(this);
        }

        // some properties
    }

    public interface IFlowVisitor
    {
        void Visit(Assetflow flow);
        void Visit(Cashflow flow);
    }
}

namespace Infra
{
    public class FlowVisitor : IFlowVisitor
    {
        public FlowVisitor(ICashflowMapper cashflowMapper, IAssetflowMapper assetflowMapper, IDao dao)
        {
            CashflowMapper = cashflowMapper;
            AssetflowMapper = assetflowMapper;
            Dao = dao;
        }

        private readonly ICashflowMapper CashflowMapper {get; set;}
        private readonly IAssetflowMapper AssetflowMapper {get; set;}
        private readonly IDao Dao {get; set;}

        public void Visit(Assetflow flow)
        {
            Assetflow assetflowDto = AssetflowMapper.Map(flow);
            dao.Persist(assetflowDto);
        }

        public void Visit(Cashflow flow)
        {
            CashflowDto cashflowDto = CashflowMapper.Map(flow);
            dao.Persist(cashflowDto);
        }
    }

    public interface ICashflowMapper
    {
        CashflowDto Map(Cashflow domainObject);
    }

    public interface IAssetflowMapper
    {
        AssetflowDto Map(Assetflow domainObject);
    }

    public interface IDao
    {
        void Persist(CashflowDto dto);
        void Persist(AssetflowDto dto);
    }

    public class cashflowDto 
    {
        // property bag
    }
    public class assetflowDto
    {
        // property bag
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            ICashflowMapper cashflowMapper = new CashflowMapper();
            IAssetflowMapper assetflowMapper = new AssetflowMapper();
            IDao dao = new Dao();
            IFlowVisitor visitor = new FlowVisitor(cashflowMapper, assetflowMapper, dao)
            List<IFlow> flows = new List<IFlow> { new Assetflow(), new Cashflow(), new Assetflow() };

            foreach(var flow in flows)
            {
                flow.Accept(visitor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In DDD it depends a lot on the Domain/details. Could you give us more details and code?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu I edited to add an example

Answer (score 1):

It is true that this specific Visitor's pattern implementation involves a slight pollution of the domain, but it's often better to be pragmatic than being a purist. If this would be the most practical solution with your language of choice or else you would end up with far more complex technical implementations then the pros would outweigh the cons and so be it.

Fortunately, C# supports dynamic dispatch using the `dynamic` keyword which relieves you from having an `Accept` method on your domain objects.

E.g.

```
public class FlowVisitor {

    public void Visit(IFlow flow) {
        Visit((dynamic) flow);
    }

    // Specific visit methods (private)...
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to use `dynamic` I wouldn't need visitor pattern at all. `foreach(dynamic flow in flows)` to call the right methods in a service object would do the trick. But i'm afraid of the cost of dynamic and it feels bad design, isn't it ?

Comment: @Baguette You lose compile-time errors, but you aren't polluting the domain. There is no perfect solution. You could also implement a dispatcher which accepts a `flow`, handles the dispatching logic with `if else` or pattern matching logic and delegates to the visitor.